# AWS SWF child workflow can't schedule lambda task

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-swf

SWF child workflows fail to schedule lambda tasks even though they are created with a role with access to lambda. Task fail with the error below.

ASSUME_ROLE_FAILED

Comment: Could you add some context, more details about your errors, etc...

Comment: Hey XavM, thank you for the response. I just sorted out what had gone wrong. I had not allow "iam:PassRole" on the user calling the swf api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of debugging I sorted out what was the issue.

User accessing the swf api need permission to perform action "iam:PassRole". Got it working using the policy below.

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Stmt14762077XXXXX",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "iam:PassRole"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXX:role/XXXXXXRole"
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Comment: XavM, thanks for reminding. I was waiting for the two hours countdown